# How open the SQLite database using open() in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Like the title says, I'm unable to call db.open() to open the SQLite database but my db.close() works fine. Kindly help, thanks!

```
public ProductDatabase(Context context) {
            ProductDatabaseHelper helper = new ProductDatabaseHelper(context);
            db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        }

public void insertToBarcodeDtl(BarcodeDtlData data) {
    String SeqNo = null;

    //db.open() <--------this is not working

    ContentValues vals = new ContentValues();
    vals.put("Barcode", data.barcode);
    vals.put("quantity", String.valueOf(data.quantity));
    vals.put("DocNo", data.DocNo);
    vals.put("SeqNo", data.SeqNo);
    vals.put("Time",data.DateTime);
    vals.put("Branch",data.Branch);

    db.insert(BarcodeDtl, null, vals);
    db.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean its not working

Comment: db.open() can't call (red color word)

Comment: You do not need to call open, getWritableDatabase will give you instance of db to operate on it. But you should use it when needed(inside insert..() function) and close after operation is completed.

Comment: @Harry everything go smooth if i do not using db.close(), but when i put db.close(), it will come out the error  (attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase:), so i guess i have to open the db when i use this function again.

Comment: Yes, that's what I told you in comment. Same way done in below answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method `open()` for sqlitehelper. Therefore you are getting error. `getWritableDatabase()` will give you instance of db to operate on it. But you should use it when needed(inside insert..() function) and close after operation is completed.

We have cursor open() method but not for sqliteHelper.

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); this is not working in my class, can u advise

Comment: U need to create a class that should have extended SqliteOpenHelper.